# PHP - Session randomly destroyed

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, garbage-collection

I use these lines to activate my session in PHP:

```
session_name("DELogin");
session_set_cookie_params((60*60*24*14), "/", ".myweb.com");
session_start();
```

However, the session *randomly* stops working (it seems), before the set expiration time (or even a browser session).
As you can see, it is supposed to last for for 2 weeks.
Is there some setting that needs to be altered?

I do not have access to php.ini, but I can change those settings through .htaccess (right?).
I saw `session.gc_probability`, `session.gc_divisor` and `session.gc_maxlifetime` but I thought it should work without altering these settings. (If I should alter these, please respond)

Thanks in advance

*EDIT:*
I tried both Eugen Rieck's and Dan Walker's suggestion, to no avail.
I set the settings in my .htaccess file, so I didn't have to include them on every page:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1209600
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 1209600

php_value session.cookie_domain ".mydomain.com"
php_value session.name "DELogin"
php_value session.auto_start 1
```

However, it still is 'cleared' after some time. (Investigation lead to the discovery the session still being there, but testing for `$_SESSION['id']` resulted false, which should when the user is not logged in).
So either the `$_SESSION['id']` is changed to false, or the session is deleted and automatically (re-)generated with `$_SESSION['id']` false.

What should I do?

Comment: How are you determining that the session stops working? Is there some where else in the code the `session_start` or something similar is being called that could possibly reset the session?

Comment: @BotskoNet Well, not that I know of. Only when the user logs him/herself out, it destroys the session (and I'm pretty sure it is only called when the user logs out)

Comment: Per your recent post update, the session would not be re-created with the same keys, so it's an issue with the `$_SESSION['id']` losing its value. Run some debug statements near everything that could touch that value and find out what might be altering it.

Comment: @BotskoNet Ok, I will be, but what do you mean with "re-created with the same keys"? I didn't say it was recreated with the same keys. All I can see is that the cookie is still there, but that's logical because it should since `session.auto_start` is set to `1`.

Comment: @BotskoNet I did, but I can't find anything. The thing is, when I log in and leave it at page (let's call it) A I can refresh it infinitely without the session being destroyed and thus being logged out. However, If I leave the computer on page A for over an hour, and then refresh it, (apparently my session is destroyed) and I am logged out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the session cookie lifetime variable?

`ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","3600"); //an hour`

Also, you can check what settings are set in the PHP.ini file by creating a file called phpinfo.php and popping the following in it:

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

And browsing to it.

Comment: As someone else has said, I would try debugging your code very carefully, using print_r or var_dump.

Answer (score 0):

For a session to work, it must be valid on both sides: Server and client. Your cookie parameters apply only to the client side, so the server side is left to the standard PHP cleanup mechanism. The parameter you need to look into is [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)